# replace element by element different arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array :

`a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])`

The array may be reshaped to `a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])`, whatever is more convenient.

Now, I have an array :

```
b = np.array([[11,22,33,44], [55,66,77,88]])
```

I want to replace to each of these elements the corresponding elements from a.

The `a` array will always hold as many elements as b has.

So, array b will be :

`[1,2,3,4],`  `[5,6,7,8]`

Note, that I must keep each b subarray dimension to `(4,)`. I don't want to change it.So, the `idx` will take values from `0 to 3`.I want to make `a` fit to `every four values`.

I am struggling with reshape, split,mask ..etc and I can't figure a way to do it.

```
import numpy as np

#a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])


b = np.array([[11,22,33,44], [55,66,77,88]])

for arr in b:
    for idx, x in enumerate(arr):
        replace every arr[idx] with corresponding a value
```

Comment: Can't you just use d as a replacement for a?

Comment: @languitar:No, as I said, I will have a loop which goes down until it reaches shape (4,) and there I want to do the replacement.

Comment: "I want to replace to each of these arrays the corresponding elements from a." this is an unclear statement.  How?  What do you mean by "corresponding"?  Is it always true `len(b)==len(c), len(a)==2*len(b)`?

Comment: @DanielForsman:That's correct.`a` will have twice the elements of b.And c will be always equal to b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
i = 0
for arr in b:
    for idx, x in enumerate(arr):
        arr[idx] = a[i]
        print(arr[idx])
        i += 1
```

Output (arr[idx]): 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
If you type `print(b)` it'll output `[[1 2 3 4] [5 6 7 8]]`

Answer (score 2):

For your current case, what you want is probably:

`b, c = list(a.reshape(2, -1))`

This isn't the cleanest, but it is a one-liner.  Turn your 1D array into a 2D array with with the first dimension as 2 with `reshape(2, -1)`, then `list` splits it along the first dimension so you can directly assign them to `b, c`

You can also do it with the specialty function [`numpy.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html)

`b, c = np.split(a, 2)`

EDIT: Based on accepted solution, vectorized way to do this is

`b = a.reshape(b.shape)`

Comment: Nice,thanks,but what can I do in [this situation](http://pastebin.com/hHECNdHf).(I edited my post)

Comment: Thanks for this solution.(upvoting)

Comment: Can't see your pastebin, but if you always want to split in half you'd want `b=a.reshape(2,-1)`.  if you always want 4 elements (and len(a) is always divisible by 4) you can do `b=a.reshape(-1,4)`

Comment: Thank you very much for the info!

Answer (score 0):

`b = a[:len(a)//2]
c = a[len(a)//2:]`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm quite new to Python but this worked for me:

```
    for i in range (0, len(a)//2):
        b[i] = a[i]
    for i in range (len(a)//2,len(a)):
        c[i-4] = a[i]
```

by printing the 3 arrays I have the following output:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
[1 2 3 4]
[5 6 7 8]
```

But I would go for Daniel's solution (the split one): 1 liner, using numpy API, ...

Comment: Hi, I edited my post.The thing is that I must replace at the same time only b array (edited in post)

Comment: I added another answer for more clarity ;)