# add and delete elements to array based on one reference array

Tags: python, numpy

This is a continuation from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42246021/replace-element-by-element-different-arrays).

If I have an array `a` and an array `b` and `a` can be smaller or larger than `b`.Is there a way , having as base array the `a`, to replace all elements of `b` (element by element) with elements of `a`?

For example, this works because `a` has as many elements as `b`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
b = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[11,22,33,44]])
print(b[0].shape)

i= 0
for el in b:
    for idx,x in enumerate(el):
        el[idx] = a[i]
        i+= 1

print(b)
[[1 2 3 4]
 [5 6 7 8]]
```

Now, for example, `a` can be:

`a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])`

and `b`:

`b = np.array([11,22,33,44])`

The result I want is `b = [1,2,3,4,5]` because all the 4 elements of `b` are replaced by the first 4 elements of `a` and I add one more element to `b` (the last of `a`) in order to be the same size as `a`(my reference array).

If I have :

`a = np.array([1,2,3])` and `b = np.array([6,7,8,9])` , then the result b array will be : `b = [1,2,3]` , so I deleted one element from `b` (to be the same size as `a`) and replaced the rest with the `a` elements.

Now, the whole problem is that:

I will have an array which has number of elements multiples of `a` size.

So , `a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])`

`arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])`

`b = np.array([[0,1,2,3], [4,5,6,7]])`

I want to replace the elements from `arr` to `b` in multiples of `a` size (hence 5).

So , final `b = [ [1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10])`

Comment: Can you just write -> b = np.array(a)  ?

Comment: bit confused with definition of `arr` and `a` here. Can you tell what is `arr` in your first example? Is it `a=np.array([1])` and `arr=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])`?

Comment: @Rohanil:In my first example `arr` was just the elements of b( I changed the name to `el` now)if you mean that.Generally, I want to replace all `b` elements by `arr` values by multiples of `a` size (so by every 5 elements in my example)

Comment: When do you want `a` to add a row?  Only when `b.size // a.size > 1, b.size % a.size == 0`?

Comment: And what happens when `a.size % b.shape[1] /= 0`?

Comment: @DanielForsman:Hi, the answer I accepted deals with this problem,thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try list slicing assuming b is always either 2d or 1d

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
b = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[11,22,33,44]])
print(b[0].shape)

list_arr = arr.tolist()
slice_factor = a.size
j=0

temp = []

for j in range(0,len(list_arr),slice_factor):
    k = min(j + slice_factor,len(list_arr))
    temp.append(list_arr[j:k])

b = np.array(temp)

print(b)
[[1 2 3 4 5]
 [6 7 8 9 10]]
```

Comment: Thanks!Great!And it works for every size, even if b.size/a.size <1 (upvoted)

Comment: That . . .doesn't give the output you asked for.

Comment: Please correct your output to be right.The result `b` is `[[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10]]` and not `[[1 2 3 4]
 [5 6 7 8]]`

Comment: I created [another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42283851/replace-elements-in-array-with-class-instances) question.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want

```
b = arr.reshape(-1, a.size)
b
Out[291]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10]])
```

Comment: Thanks!It works great!(upvoted because I already accepted)! It gives the same results as the accepted answer (I am answering to your comment below)

Comment: Accepted answer has output `b=[[1 2 3 4] [5 6 7 8]]`, which is a different size and value than my answer.  Which is correct?

Comment: No, it's the same if you run the code.Just the poster have placed wrong output ( I will notify him)

Comment: I created [another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42283851/replace-elements-in-array-with-class-instances) question.