# Replace elements in array with class instances

Tags: python, numpy

This is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42267829/add-and-delete-elements-to-array-based-on-one-reference-array) so please read it first to understand what I am trying to do.

Now, I want to make the replacement when I have class instances.Something like:

```
import numpy as np

class B():
    def __init__(self, a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b


arr = np.array([ [1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10] ])

b1 = np.array([B(100,'a'),
               B(11,'b'),
               B(300,'c'),
               B(33,'d')])

b2 = np.array([B(45,'a'),
              B(65,'b'),
              B(77,'c'),
              B(88,'d')])

# My d array will be like that and I will have to 
# run 3 loops as below . I can't change that
d = np.array([[b1],[b2]],dtype=object)

# Replace the elements
for i in d:
    for y in i:
        for idx,el in enumerate(y): 
            #y[idx].a = arr.reshape(-1,5) # 5 is the size of every sublength of arr
            #print(y[idx].a)
            pass

# Show the updated values
for i in d:       
    for y in i:
        for idx,x in enumerate(y):
            print(y[idx].a)
```

I can't use the `b = arr.reshape(-1, a.size)` because this must run outside the loops.But, as I said the `b` array will be the `y[idx].value` , so I can't just place it in the 3rd loop because I will acquire wrong results, neither can I place it outside the 3rd loop because I will not have access to the `value` part of the class instance.

I want my result to be:

```
b1 = np.array([B(1,'a'),
               B(2,'b'),
               B(3,'c'),
               B(4,'d'),
               B(5,'d')])

b2 = np.array([B(6,'a'),
              B(7,'b'),
              B(8,'c'),
              B(9,'d'),
              B(10,'d')])
```

So, I want to fill only the `a` part for example of the B class instances.
And note,that as before ( in previous question) the `B` is expanded to hold all the 5 values from `arr`.

In a few words, check the length of each sublist of `arr` (which is 5 now), 
and update the `d` values accordingly.So, if `b1` and `b2` have 4 values, they must become 5 values (the first 5 values from `arr` and the next 5 values from `arr`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I add

```
print(d.shape)
print(d)
```

and get

```
2249:~/mypy$ python3 stack42283851.py 
(2, 1, 4)
[[[<__main__.B object at 0xb71d760c> <__main__.B object at 0xb71d7aac>
   <__main__.B object at 0xb71d7acc> <__main__.B object at 0xb71e5cec>]]

 [[<__main__.B object at 0xb391718c> <__main__.B object at 0xb39171ac>
   <__main__.B object at 0xb39171cc> <__main__.B object at 0xb39171ec>]]]
```

adding a `__repr__` to `B` I get

```
1231:~/mypy$ python3 stack42283851.py 
(2, 1, 4)
[[[B(100, a) B(11, b) B(300, c) B(33, d)]]

 [[B(45, a) B(65, b) B(77, c) B(88, d)]]]
```

Adding

```
import itertools
for a,b in itertools.zip_longest(arr[0,:],b1):
     print(a,b)
```

produces

```
1 B(100, a)
2 B(11, b)
3 B(300, c)
4 B(33, d)
5 None
```

Changing that to:

```
newlist = []
for a,b in itertools.zip_longest(arr[0,:],b1):
    if b is not None:
        new_b = B(a, b.b)
        last_b = b
    else:
        new_b = B(a, last_b.b)
    newlist.append(new_b)
print(np.array(newlist))
```

produces

```
[B(1, a) B(2, b) B(3, c) B(4, d) B(5, d)]
```

Assign that to `b1`, and repeat for `a[1,:]` and `b2`.

To be a little cleaner I could write that `new_b` code as a function, and rewrite the loop as a list comprehension.

Yes, I could modify `b` in place, e.g.

```
b.a = a
```

but since I need to create a new `B` object to replace the `None`, why bother.  I can't add the new `B` object to the original `b1` array.  So it is simpler to create a new array via a list.

---

I can do an in-place change of `d` and `b1` with:

```
def replace(a,b):
    b.a = a
f = np.frompyfunc(replace, 2, 1)
f(arr[:,None,:4], d)      # produces array of None; ignore
print(d)
print(b1)

[[[B(1, a) B(2, b) B(3, c) B(4, d)]]  # chgd d

[[B(6, a) B(7, b) B(8, c) B(9, d)]]]
[B(1, a) B(2, b) B(3, c) B(4, d)]    # chgd b1
```

I'm just using `frompyfunc` as a lazy mans way of broadcasting `arr` against `d` and iterating over all elements.  Note that I have to change `arr` to match `d` shape.  Also this does not add any new `B()`.  Obviously you can't do that in-place.

---

My `B` is

```
class B():
    def __init__(self, a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'B(%s, %s)'%(self.a, self.b)
```

---

Playing with `frompyfunc` some more:

```
getB_b = np.frompyfunc(lambda x: x.b, 1,1)   # fetch b attributes
print(getB_b(d))
#[[['a' 'b' 'c' 'd']]
#
# [['a' 'b' 'c' 'd']]]

mkB = np.frompyfunc(B, 2,1)   # build array of B() with broadcasting
print(mkB(arr, ['a','b','c','d','e']))
# [[B(1, a) B(2, b) B(3, c) B(4, d) B(5, e)]
#  [B(6, a) B(7, b) B(8, c) B(9, d) B(10, e)]]

print(mkB(arr[:,:4], getB_b(d[:,0,:])))
# [[B(1, a) B(2, b) B(3, c) B(4, d)]
#  [B(6, a) B(7, b) B(8, c) B(9, d)]]
```

---

**edit for comments**

```
arr1 = np.array([ [1,2],[6,7] ])
newlist = []
for a,b in itertools.zip_longest(arr1[0,:],b1):
    if b is not None:
        new_b = B(a, b.b)
        last_b = b
    else:
        new_b = B(a, last_b.b)
    newlist.append(new_b)
print(np.array(newlist))
```

produces

```
[B(1, a) B(2, b) B(None, c) B(None, d)]
```

When `arr` is shorter, `a` will be `None` (instead of `b`); so we need to test for that

```
def foo(arr,bn):
    newlist = []
    for a,b in itertools.zip_longest(arr,bn):
        print(a,b)
        if a is None:
            pass
        else:
            if b is not None:
                new_b = B(a, b.b)
                last_b = b
            else:
                new_b = B(a, last_b.b)
            newlist.append(new_b)
    return newlist
print(np.array(foo(arr1[0,:],b1)))  # arr1 shorter
print(np.array(foo(arr[0,:], b2)))  # arr longer
```

testing:

```
1 B(1, a)
2 B(2, b)
None B(3, c)
None B(4, d)
[B(1, a) B(2, b)]

1 B(6, a)
2 B(7, b)
3 B(8, c)
4 B(9, d)
5 None
[B(1, a) B(2, b) B(3, c) B(4, d) B(5, d)]
```

Nothing special or magical; just a matter making sure I get the `if` tests and indentation right.

Comment: Also, is there a way to use `d` instead of iterating 2 times?One for `b1` and one for `b2`?

Comment: And second, if I want to replace also the b field of B class , I will use new_b = B(a, b)?And what about the `itertools.zip_longest()`.I have to put another array which holds the `b` values.So, run again from the beginning the whole loop?

Comment: And I haven't tested if it works for the opposite way.If, we need to substract elements from B and not add (in case len(a[0]) and len(a[1]) is smaller than 4 for this example

Comment: I added a couple of functions that make operating on array of `B's` easier.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the solution.I am using the approach with the itertools.Two things. 1) When len(arr[0]) < len(b1), the updated B class has None objects.is there a way to delete these during the itertools loop? 2) [Here](http://pastebin.com/yuyTLUgF) I have a problem which I describe there ( values and errors have the same size/elements) and B has 3 attributes(value,error,timestamp).Thank you very much for the

Comment: In the `zip_longest` loop, you could skip the `append` if an element is `None`.  That loop is building a new list, so at each step you do whatever works.  It's a little trickier if that loop is in a `list comprehension`, but still possible.

Comment: You mean sth like [this](http://pastebin.com/LXRs97QX)?Still prints `None`.And thanks for your help (upvoted)

Comment: Sorry, I'll have to look at it in more detail tomorrow.

Comment: I've reworked the `zip_longest` loop to handle the cases where either `a` or `b` is `None`.  If `a` is `None` we don't append anything; otherwise we make a new `B`.

Answer (score 0):

Make the replacement block like this. Also note this assumes your arr will be strictly in multiples of 5 and there will be as many blocks like b1,b2 etc as there are blocks in arr as given in the example.

```
for i,b_arr in enumerate(d):
    temp_arr = []
    for j in range(5):
        if j<len(b_arr)
            temp_arr.append(B(arr[i,j],b_arr[j].b))
        else:
            temp_arr.append(B(arr[i,j],b_arr[-1].b))
     d[i] = np.array(temp_arr) ## not sure if this step is right, not too familiar with numpy.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and sorry for late response.That didn't work for me though (also, it gives `numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'b'`) in the `temp_arr.append(B(arr[i,j],b_arr[j].b))`