# Performance impact of Python classes: Scientific Computing

Tags: python, performance, numpy, numba

So I'm in the process of writing a particle model. This simulation will involve creating a number of particles with attributes like species index (to identify particle type), and position/velocity in 3D space. It will also have properties based on it's position within the space that will be calculated during the simulation run. I've previously been running this models using a giant numpy array, where each row corresponds to a single particle, and each column a particle attribute.

My main question is this: If I was to create a class "Particles" so that I could generate instances representing each particle, is there a performance hit in terms of computational speed? If I wanted to run a program with a million particles, is it more efficient to have all the numbers in one big array (even though it's not quite as readable), or is it just as efficient to use instances of this class, and modify the instance attributes as the simulation progresses? Or is it that the classes are fine, but storing that many class instances in a Python list/NumPy array really slows down the execution?

As an aside, this program will be used with the python module "Numba" that has a great deal of optimization for numerical computation (specifically via things like the jitclass http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/jitclass.html#numba.jitclass). However, I don't want to destroy the performance benefits of this module by declaring variables in my simulation that cause it to run inefficiently.

Thanks!

Comment: If you can optimize the classes down to a struct, there won't be performance penalties really using jitclasses. That said, most work in my field traditionally writes C++ extensions and then wraps them in Python using a wrapper like SWIG or Boost::Python. Ultimately, write simple test cases and profile, profile, profile.

Comment: I don't know what `numba` can do, but normally object dtype arrays are much slower than numeric ones.  Like lists these array values are actually pointers to objects elsewhere in memory.  See my recent answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46350208/numpy-arrays-vs-lists-for-custom-classes.

Comment: What's the motivation for creating the Particles class - better abstraction? If so, you might create a class representing a population of particles, with methods to get/modify particle information. That would give you the ability to create higher-level abstractions for dealing with particles, but also store the underlying particle data in an array, so you don't scatter the data across memory.

Comment: If you're *really* concerned with performance, you might be better off taking the time to implement your code in a compiled language like C or C++. Cython could be a good intermediate step. But ultimately, benchmarking is the only way to get the "right" answer for your application. Try making some toy problems that are representative of your real problem and see how the two approaches compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've previously been running this models using a giant numpy array

Sounds like a good idea.

> If I was to create a class "Particles" so that I could generate instances representing each particle, is there a performance hit in terms of computational speed?

It will probably be much slower.

Your existing solution with NumPy arrays lets you represent all your particles in one big array:

```
id species x y z dx dy dz
id species x y z dx dy dz
id species x y z dx dy dz
```

If you change it to use a class instance per particle, you could still keep them in a NumPy array (or list), but then it will look like this:

```
object -> [id species x y z dx dy dz]
object -> [id species x y z dx dy dz]
object -> [id species x y z dx dy dz]
```

That's four N+1 objects you need to allocate instead of 1 (the array).

I'd stick with the original design, the giant NumPy array, unless it is causing major problems.

Comment: Honestly probably the best answer short of diving into C++ with Cython/Swig/Boost. Jitclasses may be faster, but I don't believe they're treated as objects in NumPy, which means pointers and therefore non-contiguous storage, so slow access and additional overhead. A C++ extension would solve a lot of these issues, and would be trivial to implement, but for such a simple example isn't worth the effort (not to mention the packaging issues).

Answer (score 0):

You should use structured datatypes here:

```
particle_dtype = np.dtype([
    ('id', int),
    ('species', (np.unicode_, 16)),
    ('pos', np.float32, 3),
    ('vel', np.float32, 3)
])

particles = np.empty(100, dtype=particle_dtype)
particles[0]['id'] = 1
particles['pos'] += particles['vel'] * dt
```